# Using a lib with enabled exception handling in an application where exception handling is turned off

Tags: c++, exception

This question is about a C++ library for Windows and we use Visual C++ as our compiler.

We enable exception handling compiler option in our library. We also use throw/catch in a few places.

One of our customers says that they disable exception handling option in their application. Now the question is, whether they would experience any problems if they use our library with their application.

Comment: Yes, they would experience problems. But then they're probably used to that. After all, what does the std lib do on errors it is supposed to throw exceptions for when exceptions are turned off? And what reasons do you have to turn off exceptions except that your code isn't exception-safe? (And, as we all found out about a decade ago, writing code in that fashion leads you to the dark side of programming. May `std::exception` be with you!)

Answer (score 0):

If any exceptions can get emitted out of your library than yes indeed they could have problems. Consider if your library threw an exception that wasn't caught and then propagated back to the application. Since the app isn't built with support for exceptions it won't know how to handle it and most likely will behave incorrectly. If you're lucky it'll crash rather than silently failing in some obscure way.

If you catch all exceptions internally within the library and use only return codes to signal problems to the outside world then things may work out ok (note that this means constructors of public API classes can't throw, and throwing is the only way they can report problems).

Comment: "_If you catch all exceptions internally within the library and use only return codes to signal problems to the outside world then things may work out ok_" Things *_may_* work out ok? I would be very interested in some more details/facts in this scenario. Is that "officially" supported/supposed to work? By the C++ standard? By a particular compiler? Does it depend on the compiler? Can it be undefined behavior (UB) in any scenario? (always given that we do catch all exceptions within the library and don't leak them across the boundary)